# Why autobind of core-decorators define THE BIND FUNCTION twice?

Tags: javascript

This is the source code [autobind.js](https://github.com/jayphelps/core-decorators/blob/master/src/autobind.js).
I am confused of the getter method.The getter method return a `boundFn`, but also define a boundFn on "this"，why? For the efficiency?

```
get() {
  // ...omit
  const boundFn = bind(fn, this);
  defineProperty(this, key, {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    // NOT enumerable when it's a bound method
    enumerable: false,
    value: boundFn
  });
  return boundFn;
},
```

Comment: `For the efficiency?` probably.

Answer (score 0):

I test like this.

```
function Foo(){}
Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, 'test', {
  get() {
    console.log('123');
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'test', {
      get(){
        console.log('456');
        return '456';
      }
    })
    return '123'
  }
});
var a = new Foo();
a.test; //FirstTime: 123,
a.test; //and then always: 456,
```

For the efficiency.It will not always lookup the prototype chain.I think so.